# SQLite - complex queries

Tags: sqlite

I am getting random row from my table using the following query:

```
SELECT value_id FROM table1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

I have 3 tables:
table1 and table2 - they are tables that have an id of a row and its value.
there is as well table3 which has as its columns IDs of rows in table1 and table2.

i.e. :

```
table1:
1 - Canada
2 - USA
3 - UK
4 - France
5 - Africa
6 - China

table2:
1 - New York
2 - Vancouver
3 - Paris
4 - London
5 - Ottawa
6 - Los Angeles

table3: (without table3 rowid)
1 - 2
1 - 5
2 - 1
2 - 6
3 - 4
4 - 3
```

So from table 3 I can say that New York is a city in USA, and so on. And as well in table3 I can have undefined values. (In the example they are Africa and China so I don't want to get them in a result)

What I want to do is to get from table1 random IDs but only those that are defined in table3. In this particular case I don't want to receive 5 and 6 as a result.

How can I rewrite my query to achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
The problem is that when I am trying to get a row which row in table3 is not defined, application cruses. It is not NULL, as I wrote before, it just doesn't exist in table3. How can I rewrite the query to properly handle my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told us how the fields in `table3` are named, but supposing for example they're named `tab1_id` and `tab2_id` with the obvious meanings, try:

```
SELECT table1.value_id 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.value_id=table3.tab1_id
WHERE table3.tab2_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: order by random() = order by table1.value_id

Comment: Thank you, that is what I need. And if I don't have a value defined in table3, how to make sure that I will not get that result in my query?

Comment: That is NOT what you need - you need random ROW and not random COLUMN?
I've answered lower with proper SQL.

Comment: The problem is that when I am trying to get a row which row in table3 is not defined, application cruses. It is not NULL, as I wrote before, it just doesn't exist in table3. How can I rewrite the query to properly handle my case?

Comment: the INNER JOIN will exclude all rows in table1 which have no corresponding one in table3 -- that's the *definition* of INNER join (as distinguished from OUTER joins).

Answer (score 1):

Order by Random() means that it will randomly order by different column.

Use this:

```
SELECT value_id FROM table3
  WHERE rowid>=random() % (SELECT max(rowid) FROM table3) 
  AND second_value IS NOT NULL
  LIMIT 1;
```

don't know the name of column2, so I've called it second_value

Answer (score 0):

Not an SQLite question but a generic SQL issue. You want to test for NULL in the field values, e.g.

```
SELECT f1 FROM table
 WHERE f2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Order by Random() means that it will randomly order by different column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rowid FROM table1
WHERE rowid IN ( SELECT DISTINCT table1_id FROM table3 )
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

This query means "choose at random a row from `table1` which has an entry in `table3`".

Every row in table1 equal likelihood of being selected (`DISTINCT`) as long as it is referenced at least once in `table3`.

If you are trying to get ALL columns from table1 that are in table3, then you should remove the "`ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`" clause.